# DBI::dbGetQuery on databases too slow

Tags: r, shiny-reactivity

I have 6 tables under one schema. There are 300 000 rows each
I use DBI::dbGetQuery to query all the table on like this:

```
myRedshift <- DBI::dbConnect(RPostgreSQL::PostgreSQL(), 
                             dbname = 'dbname',
                             host = 'host',
                             port = 5439,
                             user = "user", 
                             password = "password")

 cis_has_bdpm_data <- data.frame( DBI::dbGetQuery(myRedshift, "select * from synapps.table1"))
cis_cip_bdp_data <- data.frame( DBI::dbGetQuery(myRedshift, "select * from synapps.table2"))
medicam_data <- data.frame( DBI::dbGetQuery(myRedshift, "select * from synapps.table3"))
outpatient_data <- data.frame( DBI::dbGetQuery(myRedshift, "select * from synapps.table4"))
open_medic_data <- data.frame( DBI::dbGetQuery(myRedshift, "select * from synapps.table5"))
hospital_drugs_data <- data.frame( DBI::dbGetQuery(myRedshift, "select * from synapps.table5"))
pmsi_data  <-data.frame( DBI::dbGetQuery(myRedshift, "select * from synapps.table6"))
```

but it is very slow, it takes like 1min to query all the tables. 
So my question is: is it normal to take this long ? Is there a way to speed it up ?

Comment: In my experience with RODBC (another database connect package) it's not unusual for it to take that amount of time for large databases.

Comment: I was thinking maybe it was the transformation into a dataframe that make everything slow

Comment: [RPostgres](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RPostgres) could be faster than RPostgreSQL, you should give it a try.

Comment: Plus I don't think you need to wrap `data.frame()` around `dbGetQuery()`, the result set you get should already be a data frame.

Comment: @Scarabee I try it, it seems to run faster than before, thanks :)